# transforming tree to sequence of elements

Tags: xquery

I have something like this

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>1</c>
        <d>2<e>3</e></d>
    </b>
</a>
```

and I want to obtain a sequence like this

```
<a/>
<b/>
<c>1</c>
<d>2<e>3</e></d>
```

that is, when recursing, every time an element occurs which does not have a text node, I want to output the element as an empty element, whereas every time an element with a text node occurs, I want to output it as it is. Of course, the text nodes in the above input have to be space-normalized.

If I put it through a standard identity transform,

```
declare function local:copy($element as element()) as element() {
   element {node-name($element)}
      {$element/@*,
          for $child in $element/*
              return
                  if ($child/text())
                  then $child
                  else (element {node-name($child)}{$child/@*}, local:copy($child))
      }
};
```

<b> gets reconstructed as a full element (containing <c> and <d>), but if I remove the element constructor, it does not get output at all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get the fourth line in your example output, I'm just guessing what you want is actually this:

```
<a/>
<b/>
<c>1</c>
<d>2</d>
<e>3</e>
```

You don't need any functions. Just list all elements, reconstruct one with same name and include it's text node children.

```
for $element in //*
return element { local-name($element) } { $element/text() }
```

This version is even shorter, but I think it requires XQuery 3.0, because earlier versions did not allow element constructors in step expressions:

```
//*/element { local-name(.) } { text() }
```

Comment: Thanks, Jens, for showing me the way.

Actually, I did want the fourth line as I wrote it. I should have written that <a>, <b>, <c> and <d> are listable. 

I get the output I need with this:

`for $element in ($input, $input//*)[local-name(.) = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')]
        return 
            if ($element/text()) 
            then element { local-name($element) } { $element/node() }
            else element { local-name($element) } { $element/text() }
`